# Phonegap/Cordova cancel fileTransfer download

Tags: ios, cordova, download

Does anyone know a way of cancelling a fileTransfer.download() on iOS Phonegap? The documentation is very simple, I suspect it isn't implemented yet.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

I would like to prevent the callbacks from firing if cancelled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...yes, this looks like a piece we've missed in the API. I've raised an issue on JIRA for it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-836

Comment: Thanks Simon. For now I just worked out a way by matching a variable when the callback is invoked. But this doesn't actually cancel the download.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a timeout for the download?